# Is iqamah necessary for Qaza Farz?

Tags: salat, fard

AssalamElaikum,
Qaza Farz has different rules as I searched it on internet. For instance I came to know that we can offer Qaza Farz after Asr time expires. I have question about iqamah. As I know Iqamah is necessary for Farz Namaz. Is it necessary for Qaza Farz also?

Somebody please guide me according to Quran, Sunnah and Hadith.

Zulfi.

Comment: Anything that is applicable in a prayer on time might be performed in a prayer which was delayed. Iqamah is a sunnah of the prayer, which may reach the status of fard kifayah. 'Asr time only expires if maghrib time starts, the time for praying sunnah or nafl may expire or maybe regarded as makrooh/haram. Fard can and must be prayed at anytime because it is a due.

Comment: AssalamElaikum, By Asr time expires, I mean the time when prayer is forbidden i.e., once a person has completed his Asr prayer, kindly see the link: https://fiqh.islamonline.net/en/times-when-prayer-is-forbidden/

Comment: Fard prayer is never forbidden that's what I've already pointed at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is prescribed to say Iqamah even when praying a delayed salah. It is recorded that the Prophet ﷺ had the Iqamah said when the prayers were delayed on the occasion of the Battle of Ahzab:

> إن المشركين شغلوا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن أربع صلوات يوم الخندق حتى ذهب من الليل ما شاء الله فأمر بلالا فأذن ثم أقام فصلى الظهر ثم أقام فصلى العصر ثم أقام فصلى المغرب ثم أقام فصلى العشاء
>
> The idolaters kept Allah's Messenger ﷺ distracted from four prayers on the Day of Al-Khandaq (the battle of the Trench) until as much as Allah willed of the night had passed.
>
> So he ordered Bilal to call the Adhan, then he called the Iqamah to Zuhr, then he called the Iqamah to pray Asr, then he called the Iqamah to pray Maghrib, then he called the Iqamah to pray Isha.
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:179) ,  [Sunan an-Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:622)</sup>

Note that Iqamah for a congregation is either Fard al-Kifayah or Sunnah Mu'akkadah depending on the madhab. While for an individual it is mustahab.

Comment: AssalamElaikum, Sorry what you mean by madhab?